# Sending e-mail in C# .NET captcha block

Tags: c#, .net, gmail, captcha

I have a serious issue in sending email in C#. This is the code:

```
SmtpClient newSmpt = new SmtpClient()
    {
        Host = "smtp.googlemail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mail@gmail.com", "password"),
        Timeout = 30000
    }

string body = 'html body';
String bodyEmail = email.Replace("@", "<span>@</span>");
bodyEmail = bodyEmail.Replace(".", "<span>.</span>");
body = body.Replace("<%email%>", bodyEmail);
body = body.Replace("<%name%>", name);
body = body.Replace("<%name%>", name);

MailMessage mailMessageMox = new MailMessage("mail@gmail.com", "info@mail.it", "Title", body);
mailMessageMox.IsBodyHtml = true;
newSmpt.Send(mailMessageMox);
```

With this code I managed to send mail correctly. Sometimes I catch an exception from the Send method with this message: "the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated". As you can see, the EnableSsl property is set to true, as told in other posts. When I go to gmail and try to login with the credentials used in the code, it asks me to enter a captcha code. After entering the captcha, I can login and then the code works fine. The problem is that this can happen too many times.

How to block captcha asking in gmail?

Answer (score 1):

Unlocking captcha for the account you are using should solve your problem:

http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do the trick. I clicked on the link and used the account from the .NET web service within 10 minutes, but after two days it went blocked again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your problem is with sending an email through the `SmtpClient`.
It should work just fine

Check out this Question, for all the settings that is needed to send from Gmail via `SmtpClient`

[Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

There should be a configuration in your Gmail account that will enable you to send emails without the need to verify your credentials using captcha.